# pyarrow: how to save casted column's values in same table?

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

i'm beginner in pyarrow and trying to cast my timestamp with AM/PM prefix.

I have a column ['Datetime'] with such values:

```
   "2021/07/25 12:00:00 AM",
   "2022/06/28 11:58:00 PM",
   "2022/03/11 10:30:00 AM",
```

and i'm trying to get these:

```
2021-07-25 12:00:00,
2022-06-28 11:58:00,
2022-03-11 10:30:00,
```

Ideally, want make this transformation in **pyarrow.csv.read_csv** something like that:

```
table = csv.read_csv('my_data.csv',
                     convert_options=csv.ConvertOptions(
    column_types={
        'Datetime': pa.timestamp[s],
                 }
                                                        )
                    )
```

and after that write this table to parquet.

At the same time i know how to convert this separate from my table

```
pc.strptime(table.column("Incident Datetime"), format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %p', unit='s')
```

But i don't understand how to cast this changes to my table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you can do that with `set_column` method. See cookbook here: https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/py/data.html#replacing-a-column-in-an-existing-table.

```
new_incident_datetime = pc.strptime(table.column("Incident Datetime"), format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %p', unit='s')
column_idx = 1 # Or whatever your column index happens to be.

sales_data.set_column(
  column_idx,
  "Incident Datetime",
  pa.array([30, 20, 15, 40])
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. And cookbook is really helpful tool; strange that I didn't find it earlier